# create and new action in nested resource of a one to one relationship?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have this relationship:

```
appointment has_one :feedback
feedback belongs_to :appointment
```

ROUTES:

```
resources :appointments do
  resources :feedbacks
end
```

My link to new feedback is like this:

```
new_appointment_feedback_path(@current_appointment)
```

MY FORM:

```
<%= simple_form_for [@appointment, @feedback], html: {class: 'form-horizontal'}, wrapper: :horizontal_input_group do |f| %>

<%= f.input :feedback %>

<% end %>
```

and finally in my feedback controller:

```
def new
    @appointment = Appointment.find(params[:appointment_id])
    @feedback = @appointment.build_feedback
end

def create 

end
```

The error atm:

```
NoMethodError in FeedbacksController#new
undefined method `build' for nil:NilClass
```

Can someone help me how to fix this please. tnx

UPDATE:

new action is working now.

```
I made my form like this:

<%= simple_form_for [@appointment, @appointment.build_feedback], html: {class: 'form-horizontal'}, wrapper: :horizontal_input_group do |f| %>
```

FEEDBACKS CONTROLLER:

```
def new
    @appointment = Appointment.find(params[:appointment_id])
end

def create 
    @appointment = Appointment.find(params[:appointment_id])
    @feedback = @appointment.build_feedback(feedback_params)
    if @feedback.save
        ....
    else
        render 'new' 
    end
end

def feedback_params
    params.require(:feedback).permit(:id, :feedback)
end
```

Comment: What is @current_appointment ?

Comment: '@current_appointment = @task.appointments.last', in my apppointmnents controller

Comment: Show your appointmentsController, also in which page are you putting the link_to new_appointment_feedback_path(@current_appointment)
 ?

Comment: actually, I was able to figure out the new action. I am just trying to make the create action to work. so please if u can help me. I will post it now anyway. tnx for the reply

Comment: So what's your new error? Or do you want help in general to get the create action to work?

Comment: please see the edit. ye i need help to make the create action work. If you could take a look at my code pleae. the error im getting atm is Template is missing when I try to submit my form @RailsOuter

Comment: create a show action, you are seeing this error because after the create action rails directs to the show action, but you don't have it now.

Comment: hi, already soved it, thnx for the replies.